# Awesomium WebControl In Other Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

How to correctly use `WebControl` and get value from other `thread`?

My code for usage:

```
dynamic JQRet = (JSObject)webControlMain.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"$('.surf')");
```

Comment: If you are accessing it in a background thread and it is in the ui thread you must use a Dispatcher for that.

Comment: I`m use dynamic JQRet = webControlMain.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() {
                webControlMain.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"$('.surf_ckick')");
            })); but returned data (JQRet) is not correct